# What happens to a transaction that is never commited or rolled back?

Tags: javascript, node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

What happens to an unmanaged transaction in the NodeJS Sequelize framework that is neither commited nor rolled back?

Does it time out and if yes does that throw an error? How can I configure the timeout?